# Editar ficheiros .csv em C

Tags: c, csv

Preciso de fazer um código de programação em C, no qual peço ao utilizador o nome de uma cidade, presente no primeiro ficheiro (cidades.csv), e tenho que retirar de lá o id da cidade inserida. Depois, esse id tem que corresponder a outro id, presente num segundo ficheiro (meteorologia.csv), e depois editar a informação meteorológica, presente no segundo ficheiro. Estive a fazer várias pesquisas e com alguma ajuda, consegui obter o código abaixo. Porém, quando o compilo, tudo o que está no segundo ficheiro é substituído pelos dados do primeiro ficheiro. Alguém me poderia ajudar?

```
#define TAM_STR 100

typedef struct city_t{
char city_id[TAM_STR];
char city_name[TAM_STR];
char county_name[TAM_STR];
char district_name[TAM_STR]; } city_t;

typedef struct meteo_t{
char meteo_id[TAM_STR];
char meteo_city_id[TAM_STR];
char tempt_max[TAM_STR];
char tempt_min[TAM_STR];
char humidity[TAM_STR];
char preassure[TAM_STR];
char date[11]; } meteo_t;

int editInfo(){
char city[100];    

struct city_t INFO;
struct meteo_t DATA;

printf("Qual e a cidade: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", city);

FILE* stream = fopen("cidades.csv", "r");
FILE* meteo =fopen ("meteorologia.csv","w");

if("cidades.csv" == NULL || "meteorologia.csv" == NULL)
{
    printf("Nao e possivel abrir o ficheiro\n");
    return -1;
}

char line[1024];
while (fgets(line, 1024, stream) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(line, "%s", INFO.city_name);
    if(strcmp(city, INFO.city_name) == 0)
    { //pelo que me disseram, falta aqui um while
        sscanf(line, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", DATA.tempt_max, DATA.tempt_min, DATA.humidity, DATA.preassure, DATA.date);
        printf("Introduza o valor da temperatura maxima: ");
                scanf("%s", DATA.tempt_max);
                printf("Introduza o valor da temperatura minima: ");
                scanf("%s", DATA.tempt_min);
                printf("Introduza o valor da humidade: ");
                scanf("%s", DATA.humidity);
                printf("Introduza o valor da pressao: ");
                scanf("%s", DATA.preassure);
                printf("Introduza a data correspondente, no formato AAAA-MM-DD: ");
                scanf("%s", DATA.date);

                fprintf(meteo, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", DATA.tempt_max, DATA.tempt_min, DATA.humidity, DATA.preassure, DATA.date);
                printf("Informacao alterada com sucesso!");

                fclose(stream);
                fclose(meteo);
    }
    else
    {
        fputs(line, meteo);
    }
}           
}
```

O ficheiro cidades.csv tem 152 linhas e 4 colunas, com este formato:

```
id_cidade,cidade,concelho,distrito
```

como por exemplo:

```
98,Porto,Porto,Porto
```

O ficheiro meteorologia tem 152 linhas e 7 colunas, com este formato:

```
id_meteo,id_cidade,temp_max,tem_min,humidade,pressao,data
```

como por exemplo:

```
98,98,9.5,0.3,62,1025,2018-02-12
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Tinha varios erros.
Tinha um erro no sscanf que fazia que o input recebido lendo o arquivo cidades.csv fosse o codigo da cidade em vez do nome.
Depois disso tinha um if que comparava o input escrito pelo usario com o nome da cidade com o input do arquivo, no caso o codigo da cidade.
O else fazia que copiase a linha do arquivo cidades.csv para meteorologia.csv 
E mais alguns erros a seguir o codigo corrigido e funcional
Esqueci de mencionar o erro no seu arquivo cidade.csv por algum motivo quando inseridas as informações sem virgulas, por exemplo, "98,Porto,Porto,Port" da um erro no SCANF 
O certo seria inserir as informaçoes com espaços depois das virgulas, como por exemplo, "98, Porto, Porto, Porto"
Espero que agor funcione

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM_STR 100

typedef struct city_t{
char city_id[TAM_STR];
char city_name[TAM_STR];
char county_name[TAM_STR];
char district_name[TAM_STR]; } city_t;

typedef struct meteo_t{
char meteo_id[TAM_STR];
char meteo_city_id[TAM_STR];
char tempt_max[TAM_STR];
char tempt_min[TAM_STR];
char humidity[TAM_STR];
char preassure[TAM_STR];
char date[11]; } meteo_t;

int editInfo(){
char city[100];    

struct city_t INFO;
struct meteo_t DATA;

printf("Qual e a cidade: ");
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", city);

FILE* stream = fopen("cidades.csv", "r");
FILE* meteo = fopen("meteorologia.csv","w");

if("cidades.csv" == NULL || "meteorologia.csv" == NULL)
{
    printf("Nao e possivel abrir o ficheiro\n");
    return -1;
}

char line[1024];
while (fgets(line, 1024, stream) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(line, "%s%s", INFO.city_id, INFO.city_name);

    char *pointerComma = NULL;
    char *pointerCityName = NULL;
    pointerComma = strchr(INFO.city_name, ',');
    pointerCityName = INFO.city_name;

    int indexComma = pointerComma - pointerCityName;
    INFO.city_name[indexComma] = 0;

    if(strcmp(city, INFO.city_name) == 0)
    { //pelo que me disseram, falta aqui um while
        sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %s", DATA.tempt_max, DATA.tempt_min, DATA.humidity, DATA.preassure, DATA.date);
        printf("Introduza o valor da temperatura maxima: ");
        scanf("%s", DATA.tempt_max);
        printf("Introduza o valor da temperatura minima: ");
        scanf("%s", DATA.tempt_min);
        printf("Introduza o valor da humidade: ");
        scanf("%s", DATA.humidity);
        printf("Introduza o valor da pressao: ");
        scanf("%s", DATA.preassure);
        printf("Introduza a data correspondente, no formato AAAA-MM-DD: ");
        scanf("%s", DATA.date);

        fprintf(meteo, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", DATA.tempt_max, DATA.tempt_min, DATA.humidity, DATA.preassure, DATA.date);
        printf("Informacao alterada com sucesso!");

        fclose(stream);
        fclose(meteo);
    }
}

return 0;        
}


int main() {

editInfo();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda! Porém, o seu código continua a não funcionar no meu programa, e desta vez, apaga-me tudo o que tenho no ficheiro meteorologia.csv. O programa compila, mas quando introduzo a cidade a pesquisar, o programa deixa de correr